# Java, Cucumber, Maven - Feature executa sem classe alguma

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Fiz um projeto de automação de testes utilizando Eclipse + Java + Maven + Cucumber + Selenium

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Como não estou utilizando git ainda, eu exportei esse projeto para um arquivo .zip, e no meu trabalho importei ele através da opção 'Existing project into workspace'.

Meu projeto exemplificado:

**Feature** - PagarPedido

**Classe para chamar o cucumber** - PagarPedidoTest

**Classe para definir os passos** - PagarPedidoStepDef

Além de outros page objects em outro package

Notei que quando estava alterando minha classe de definição dos passos, essa mesma alteração não estava fazendo efeito algum na execução da minha feature (em casa estava tudo Ok, uma refletia a outra normalmente)

Então deletei minhas duas classes e tentei executar a feature de novo. Executou, mesmo sem nenhuma classe associada a ela. Exclui todas as classes do projeto e a feature continua executando com sucesso. Quem conhece cucumber sabe que a feature só possui anotações, não chama método algum.

Alguém sabe me explicar o porque disso acontecer? Eu sou meio que iniciante em java, um amigo disse que 'pode ser que a feature esteja pegando um jar de um path que esta setado no projeto'. Mas como faço para me certificar que é isso e resolver?

Minha feature:

```
  // package - bdd_smoke_prod

    Feature: Login with Gigya

      Scenario Outline: Login
        Given I am in the Site
        When I log in with "<UserName>" and "<Password>"
        Then I will be redirected to the home page logged under my "<Name>"

        Examples: 
          | UserName     | Password  | Name |
          | abc@abc.com  | test123   | Luis |
          | as@dfdsf.com | erwerewre | Jack  |
```

Minha runnerclass:

```
 package cucumber_tests;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(plugin= {"pretty", "json:target/"},
    features = {"src/main/java/Login.feature"})


    public class LoginTest {

    }
```

Minha definição de passos:

```
 package cucumber_tests;

    import cucumber.api.PendingException;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
    import pages.HomePage;
    import pages.Login;
    import tests.BeforeTests;
    import utils.DriverMaker;
    import utils.DriverMaker.BrowserType;

    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class LoginStepsDef  {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        HomePage dologin = new HomePage(driver);
        Login assertlogged = new Login(driver);

        @Given("^I am in the Site$")
        public void i_am_in_the_Site() throws Throwable {

            driver.get("http://www.site.com.br");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            String verificaSite = driver.getCurrentUrl();

            assertTrue(verificaSite.contains("www.site.com.br"));

            }

        @When("^I log in with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
        public void i_log_in_with_and(String email, String senha) throws Throwable {

            dologin.AcessaLogin().FazLogin(email, senha);

        }
        @Then("^I will be redirected to the home page logged under my \"([^\"]*)\"$")
        public void i_will_be_redirected_to_the_home_page_logged_under_my(String username) throws Throwable {
            assertlogged.ValidaAcesso(username); 

        }




    }
```

Ressaltando que essa classe é o único lugar do projeto capaz de reproduzir esses passos (acessar o site, fazer login, verificar se nome esta correto). Se eu deleto essa classe e tento executar a feature, eu consigo fazer tudo isso normalmente, como se a feature estivesse buscando esse código do...além?

Obrigado.

Comment: Cara nunca usei cucumber com Java, somente  Ruby, posta sua feature e seu step definition, seu step definido na Feature é unico logo se voce definir Dado que estou na tela inicial o seu step definition não tem como pegar o "jar"de outra classe. @LuísGustavoVieira

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino Primeiramente, obrigado por ajudar! Editei o post com o código. A classe que executa os passos é unica, não existe outra dela. Mas mesmo se eu deletá-la, ou deletar TODAS as classes do meu projeto, só deixando o package contendo o arquivo '.feature', mesmo assim, esse arquivo vai ser executado, abrirá o navegador, fará o login, e verificará se o nome existe. É como se estivesse puxando o código de outro lugar.

Comment: Chegando em casa vou olhar com calma